# Post form with file upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I was searching an HTML form which consists of some text-box, radio-button, check-box, text-area, select-option and browse fields with validation.

And that form use Ajax or jQuery to post data into a mysql table (each field in a form is mapped in mysql table to create a single record) and in any case (successful entry / error while inserting) also give a message.

But I failed..

any help -or- demo thank you..

Comment: I'm voting to close. What have you tried so far? My suggestion is that you first make a form without the AJAX functionality and get that working first. Then add on the AJAX functionality

Comment: What exactly are you trying todo? build the form, or fake submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ajax method to send the form data to a PHP script using POST.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You know how to process forms "normally" with PHP right? Get data from $_POST, filter it, then add to a database, or mail, or both, etc. With jQuery, it's the same thing, you just need to tell jQuery which HTTP Method you will be using (GET or POST) and direct it to a PHP script that will process the data.